# Shuffle a list within a specific range python

Tags: python, list, range, shuffle

I'm very new to Python, so bear with me. I would like to run a program that will shuffle a string of integers in a specific range, but without having to input each integer within that range. I.e., I want to randomize the list of integers from 1 to 100 without typing out (`1, 2, 3`...`100`).

Yes, I've looked at other answers to similar questions, but all are asking for one integer within a specific range, or are not answered for Python, or are asking for something way more complex. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

You can use `range()` along with `list()` to generate a list of integers, and then apply `random.shuffle()` on that list.

```
>>> lst = list(range(1,11))
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> random.shuffle(lst)
>>> lst
[4, 5, 3, 9, 2, 10, 7, 1, 6, 8]
```

---

Help on class `range` in module builtins:

```
class range(object)
 |  range(stop) -> range object
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
 |
 |  Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)
 |  to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.
 |  start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.
 |  These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
 |  When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
```

Comment: And what if I already have a list, but just want to shuffle a sub-list? I think that was the original question.

Comment: @user2061057 Something like: `sublist = lis[5:10]; random.shuffle(sublist); lis[5:10] = sublist`.

Comment: With Python 3.9, this answer generates a TypeError when calling random.shuffle(lis).  Instead of lis = range(1,11), use lis = list(range(1,11)).

Answer (score 10):

In case you want the entire population within a given range, As @Ashwini proposed you can use [random.shuffle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

In Case you are interested in a subset of the population, you can look forward to use [random.sample](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
>>> random.sample(range(1,10),5)
[3, 5, 2, 6, 7]
```

You may also use this to simulate [random.shuffle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```
>>> random.sample(range(1,10),(10 - 1))
[4, 5, 9, 3, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7]
```

**Note**, The advantage of using random.sample over random.shuffle, is , it can work on iterators, so in

- Python 3.X you don;t need to convert `range()` to list
- In Python 2,X, you can use `xrange`
- Same Code can work in Python 2.X and 3.X